# How to configure nginx to show file content instead of downloading it?

Tags: nginx

I have a directory index configured and every time I click a file it gets downloaded.

I want to tell nginx to show the content for text files instead of downloading them.

I still want the download to work when I use wget on those text files.

How can I do that?

Comment: Look [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/364370/how-can-i-make-sure-that-nginx-serves-plaintext-files-as-a-download-instead-of).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to Sergey Moiseev's comment

the answer is quite simple.

go to your configuration file and add the following

```
types {
    text/plain sh;
}
```

this maps the extension `.sh` to mime-type `text/plain`

Comment: It has a typo, it should be types { ... } as http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types

Comment: and what for the files without extension

Answer (score 7):

Nginx do this in a very simpler way.

```
location ^~ /log {
           sendfile on;
           sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
           alias  /var/log/nginx;
           autoindex on;
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

           types {
                    text/plain log;
                }
        }
```

In the above example, it will match the file with extension .log as plain text added in nginx log.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the content type in the `location` block.

In my case I want to serve a `VERSION` file, but by default the browser downloads it (because it's served as `application/x-octet-stream`). If I make nginx send it with a Content-type of text/plain, the browser will display it instead of downloading it.

```
location = /VERSION {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    add_header Cache-Control 'must-revalidate';
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
}
```