# How to configure nginx to show .ipynb scipy notebooks without downloading them

Tags: nginx

I have tried [How to configure nginx to show file content instead of downloading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671034/how-to-configure-nginx-to-show-file-content-instead-of-downloading-it/22671886) and it doesn't work for me.

Here is my nginx config.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /home/splat/files;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name files.kiwiheretic.xyz;
  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/files.kiwiheretic.xyz.access.log combined;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/files.kiwiheretic.xyz.eror.log;

location / {
    autoindex on;
 sendfile on;
 types { text/plain ipynb; }

}


}
```

I have tried *types* directive with both *ipynb* and *.ipynb* and neither seems to make any difference.  Currently there is one ipynb folder uploaded to the server and you can see for yourself that it just downloads instead of displaying the contents.  (When I say display it's contents I don't mean render it as a scipy notebook but just display the raw JSON contents.)

Anything else I can try?

Comment: it works on my nginx 1.20 with Chrome and cURL. What browser do you use?

Comment: I am using Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)